# Magento save credit card AuthCode

Tags: magento, payment-gateway

Can anyone suggest how I can save the credit card AuthCode, PayerAuth and some other less-often used fields in Magento?

I've followed a few routes, but none of them are step-by-step and they don't seem to be right for normal credit card payments.

One such example was 
[Magento payment : additional_information or payment attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939916/magento-payment-additional-information-or-payment-attribute) but this one is for billing agreements.

Kind regards,
Justin

Comment: I don't recommend this as it can violate the banking agreement with your card processor.  PCI compliance disallows you from saving that information, but this could probably work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370235/saving-extra-data-with-an-order-in-magento

Comment: I don't think that's quite the same thing, although please correct me if I'm wrong. We collect this information as we only auth on our website, and it's required so we can charge customers later. I'm not storing CV2 as this is certainly never recommended.

Comment: AuthCode - the 3 or 4 digits on the back of the card, but the idea behind that idea is scalable to the your need, as it allows you to add more data to the sales column so that it can be collected and stored when the event is fired in the conversion from quote to order, so that you can access it in the admin.

Comment: The AuthCode is provided by the card provider as the transaction takes place. You're talking about the CV2/CCV/CSC/CVD/CVVC amongst other names, which are the 3/4 digits on the back and sometimes front of the card. This should rarely be captured. What I need is a way to capture the Auth Code, PayerAuth Code (which is the code given when a customer's bank uses 3D secure). Can anyone assist?

Comment: Just create the above link and in your exchange of information, use the setCommand to set your created attributes.