# In Magento, how do I populate a new column in sales_order_grid with data from sales_flat_order?

Tags: magento

I am following Ivan's tutorial ([Adding order attribute to the orders grid in Magento 1.4.1](http://www.ecomdev.org/2010/07/27/adding-order-attribute-to-orders-grid-in-magento-1-4-1.html)) to add an extra column to the sales_order_grid table (the Shipping Description text) and it's working except it's not bring old data across from sales_flat_order to the new column in sales_order_grid.

My SQL install script adds the column correctly and because I'm using the same field name as in sales_flat_order I don't think I need an observer, however the code to import all of the existing shipping description data into the shipping_description field isn't running.

What I am doing wrong?

My SQL install script:

```
<?php
/**
 * Setup scripts, add new column and fulfills
 * its values to existing rows
 *
 */
/* @var $this Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup */
$this->startSetup();

// Add column to grid table
$this->getConnection()->addColumn(
    $this->getTable('sales/order_grid'),
    'shipping_description',
    "varchar(255) not null default ''"
);

// Add key to table for this field,
// it will improve the speed of searching & sorting by the field
$this->getConnection()->addKey(
    $this->getTable('sales/order_grid'),
    'shipping_description',
    'shipping_description'
);


// fill existing rows with data
$select = $this->getConnection()->select();
$select->join(
    array('order'=>$this->getTable('sales/order')),
    $this->getConnection()->quoteInto('order.entity_id = order_grid.entity_id',''),
    array('shipping_description' => 'shipping_description')
);

$this->getConnection()->query(
    $select->crossUpdateFromSelect(
        array('order_grid' => $this->getTable('sales/order_grid'))
    )
);

$this->endSetup();
```

I am using Magento 1.5.1 Community Edition!

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should work:

```
$select = $this->getConnection()->select();
$select->join(
    array('order_shipping'=>$this->getTable('sales/order')),//alias=>table_name
    $this->getConnection()->quoteInto(
        'order_shipping.entity_id = order_grid.entity_id',
        Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_SHIPPING
    ),//join clause
    array('shipping_description' => 'shipping_description')//fields to get
);
$this->getConnection()->query(
    $select->crossUpdateFromSelect(
        array('order_grid' => $this->getTable('sales/order_grid'))
    )
);
```

If you want, take a look at my [extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/OSdave/extension/5814/orders_grid_payment_shipping_filters) :)
HTH

Comment: Perfect! I had looked at your extension whilst I was trying to put mine together and between Ivan's post and your extension I was so close - just getting it wrong populating the data :-)  I will be sure to open source my super simple version too later on. Thanks !

Comment: actually i need one field warehouse in sales order grid

i created column name warehouse in sales_flat_order and sales_flat_order_grid table
and created attribute : warehouse with values

 //workout
 $this->addColumn('warehouse', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Warehouse'),
        'index' => 'warehouse',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'width' => '70px',          

        'options' => Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'warehouse'),

    ));

still not working, is any steps i need to follow?

Comment: The column name displayed on sales order grid, and values not display, and main thing after placed order i need maually change the warehouse values, initially the name should be display like "pick the order"
my attribute:

Comment: could you pls help me what i need to do?

Comment: @Rathinam you should open your own question if you are looking for help