# Why can't I set the auto_increment value in my magento setup script?

Tags: mysql, magento

I am creating a custom module with a few custom database tables.  I need to set the auto_increment value to 5000 rather than having the default of 1.  This can be accomplished pretty easily, but I am running into problems when trying to do it via a Magento install script.  I want to know why, and how to work around the issue.  Here are more details.

When I run the following create statement from a regular mysql client (like Heidi SQL, or the standard cli) the auto_increment value gets set correctly.  It gets set to 5000.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  myid INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  other_column INTEGER NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDb DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5000;
```

But when I put that *exact same query* into a magento install script the auto_increment is set to 1 after it runs.  To be clear, the table is created as I expect, except for the fact that the auto_increment isn't set to 5000.  Here is the code in the install script.

file: app/code/local/Mycompany/Mymodule/sql/mymodule_setup/mysql4-install-0.0.1.php

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
    CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('mytable')} (
      myid INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
      other_column INTEGER NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDb DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5000;
");
$installer->endSetup();
```

Why is this happening?  Are there any workarounds?

(I'll also mention that I have tried to set the auto_increment with an ALTER statement, and I get the same problem)

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your install script as an .sql file instead of .php mysql4-install-0.0.1.sql

Checkout Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php `_modifyResourceDb`

```
            try {
                switch ($fileType) {
                    case 'sql':
                        $sql = file_get_contents($sqlFile);
                        if ($sql!='') {
                            $result = $this->run($sql);
                        } else {
                            $result = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'php':
                        $conn = $this->_conn;
                        $result = include($sqlFile);
                        break;
                    default:
                        $result = false;
                }
```

Short answer: Script wise I don't think its possible, and using the .sql method may not work as well since it is still calling the the run(); method.

[Add an auto_increment column in Magento setup script without using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341693/add-an-auto-increment-column-in-magento-setup-script-without-using-sql)

You can also take a look at lib/Varient/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php for more deeper reference to whats going on in the background like, `multi_query` and `_splitMultiQuery`

Some more further reading for connection methods can be found here also:

[ALTER TABLE in Magento setup script without using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315660/alter-table-in-magento-setup-script-without-using-sql)

More than likely your going to have to go outside the realm of "The Magento Way" of doing things and after your module is installed make a custom post-install script that would run on your table and adjust the auto_increment directly.

Comment: Trying out the .sql method was a good idea but I got the same problem. This module needs to be compatible with Magento 1.3.x (should have mentioned that before!), so the links you provided aren't of any use unfortunately - I think that class was added in 1.4.x.  I am thinking that your last paragraph is right, that I'll need to do something outside of the normal magento way to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set the primary key that way. All my code is built the fillowing way and it works perfectly fine:

```
    <?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
    CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('mytable')} (
      myid INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment,
      other_column INTEGER NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`myid`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDb DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5000;
");
$installer->endSetup();
```